# Helpdesk Issue Tracking/Ticketing System for MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We are looking for a MOSS 2007 webpart for help desk issue tracking and ticketing.  Any recommendations?

It doesn't have to be too fancy, but would like something a little more comprehensive then the helpdesk template built into MOSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No positive news I'm afraid, I've been doing the same and everything I've seen out there has been written by people who don't know how a proper helpdesk works and just thought "logging calls... how hard could it be?".

Depending on how much logic you need building into your helpdesk "template" then you're talking about quite a considerable job that doesn't align too well with typical MOSS apps imo.

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want to hear...

Comment: I'd love to be wrong, I'm going to keep watching this question in case I am, but... sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the  helpdesk template built into MOSS for over 2 years now. It depends on the extent of the features you want. If your need is for tracking and ticketing, you can get it all within MOSS in conjuction with Sharepoint designer (A power tool if you know how to use it)